# SubmitChanges() not work when i change datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

nothing happen and nothing change when I use datagridview and `SubmitChanges()`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.book_infoDataGridView.DataSource = bookstore.book_info;
    BindingSource bds=new BindingSource();
    bds.DataSource = this.bookstore.book_info;
    this.book_infoBindingSource = bds;
    this.book_infobindingNavigator.BindingSource = bds;

}      

private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.book_infoBindingSource.EndEdit();
    bookstore.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please clear formatting

Comment: Can you please provide complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to [`.SubmitChanges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx) from your data in the `DataGridView`

```
    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var bookstoreContext = new yourContext())
        {
            var b = (BookClass)bds.Current;
            var book = bookstoreContext.Products.Single(c => c.BookId == b.BookId); //or .First()
            book.BookName = b.BookName;
            book.BookInfo = b.BookInfo;
            bookstoreContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```